# can't see google marker

Tags: marker

Can someone tell me why I can't see the marker on this map?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<style type="text/css">
    html { height: 100% }
    body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
    #map_canvas { height: 100% }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?keykey=AIzaSyBG47z_ebM8I6Ic2-rXL8QiPN5CHCOBwco&sensor=true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.998727,-0.686259),
            zoom: 18,
            minZoom: 4,
            maxZoom: 13,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            streetViewControl: false
        }; 
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions); 
    }     

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(37.998727,-0.686259), 
        map: map
    });
</script>
<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:600px; height:600px;"></div>
```

Comment: Is your enter key broken? `:/`

Answer (score 1):

Look in your browser's error console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: map is not defined
```

You need to expose that variable, since `map` is not currently visible outside of the scope of `initialize()`. Or, move the marker code into `initialize()`:

```
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.998727,-0.686259),
        zoom: 18,
        minZoom: 4,
        maxZoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        streetViewControl: false
    }; 
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(37.998727,-0.686259), 
        map: map
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, could you elaborate a little more, am very new to this and just can't get it right!

Comment: Just replace your initialize function with the one in my answer.